# Updating a singleton from daemon thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, singleton

I have a singleton where I store shared information used from different fragments.

On the other hand, I have a service that spawns a daemon thread. This thread connects to an event bus and is resposible to receive events from a external server. When it receives a new event, updates the singleton and notify the fragments through `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Is updating a singleton from a created thread without syncronization correct? I mean regarding to the Java/Android Memory Model. (The singleton can only be updated from this service/thread).

Is this approach good or are there better patterns to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the singleton pattern should be avoided in Android. Why? Because the singleton pattern uses a static instance field. Static fields like that should be avoided because the OS can unload your class and you loose all its content. So my suggestion is to remove the singleton pattern or use it inside an instance of your application (I mean extending the Application class).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the Application class instead of a singleton, but updating its data from a thread is safe? (visibility problems)

Comment: No it's not safe. You are updating the same data from two different threads, so you need to synchronize the access. Please rember to accept the answer if they are ok for you.